# How to access the object "request" within the model?

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs, strongloop

Consider the following code:

```
// common/models/test.js

module.exports = function(Test) {
    Test.observe('before save', function (ctx, next) {
        console.log(ctx.req); // <-----------
        next();
    });
};
```

In the browser console, "ctx.req" is undefined.

How to access the object "request" within the model?

Comment: You can find `accessToken` in `ctx.options` in `before save`. Also, check out [Loopback #3023](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/pull/3023).

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is in the implementation of the `context` object. In Loopback, the `context` object have many variants and all of them are not related to each other.

For example: the `context` object used in Remote hooks are different than `context` object used in Operation hooks.

Now `req` and `result` object are in remote hook's `context` object. You get `instance` object in operation hooks.

So the modified should be

```
module.exports = function(Test) {
    Test.observe('before save', function (ctx, next) {
        console.log(ctx.instance); // <-----------
        next();
    });
};
```

You can read about these context objects here:

- [Remote hook's context object](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Remote+hooks)
- [Operation hook's context object](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Operation+hooks)

Comment: ctx.instance is undefined